# Why is g_send_packet causing a crash because it's nullptr but I can't have it be anything else?

Tags: c++, extern, nullptr

Okay, so, I'm trying to debug a DLL so that it won't crash my game when I load in but it keeps doing it for some odd reason and when I debug it, it gives me an error saying "g_send_packet was nullptr" but I can't really change what it is afaik (extremely new to this kind of stuff, only coding background is lua)
As you can see, g_send_packet is defined as an extern in globals.h, which should be fine.

`extern bool* g_send_packet;`

and in globals.cpp, it's defined as

`bool* g_send_packet = nullptr;`

But, when I inject the DLL into the game I'm running, it crashes, gives me the same line as earlier  and points to this line in resolver.cpp:

`if (*g_send_packet)`

`angle1[player->EntIndex()] = player->get_eye_angles().y;`

I'm extremely confused and at this point and I'm just trying to get this to work. Any help is greatly appreciated and any extra clarification is perfectly fine with me. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Only reference found to `g_send_packet` is in [github -  smealum/butthax](https://github.com/smealum/butthax/blob/master/fwmod/exploit/source/main.c) and from the description -- I hope that isn't what you are referring to...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin God, no. What I'm referencing is a way to send/choke packets from my PC to the game's servers.